# SSRS VS05 - Create a Scale break in a Line chart

Tags: charts, graph, line, reportingservices-2005

Is there a way to add a **Scale Break** in Visual Studio 2005 for an SSRS line chart report?

The reason is because I have some data like the following:

```
Vendor   Date   Amount
------   ----   ------
Test     1/1    0.0093
Test     1/2    0.0072
Test1    1/1    0.0033
Test1    1/2   -0.0450
Volume   1/1    343203
Volume   1/2    493902
```

I'm needing to show this information all on the same line graph but since the amounts are so different, it makes the graph blend all the **Test** vendors together and all I can really see is the volume line.

I'm just needing the graph to be smart enough to show half of the height to the **Test** vendors and the other half to the **Volume** vendor. I've used some 3rd party ASP.Net tools and they called it a Scale Break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to use axis "scale breaks" is a new feature they added to SSRS 2008.  My understanding is that there is no equivalent built-in feature in SSRS 2005.